# Find the values of $x$ for which the series converges

Tags: calculus, power-series

Find the values of $x$ for which the series converges. Find the sum of the series for those values of $x$.

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos^ nx}{2^n}$$

I do not what to do. Help me with the steps pliz.

Comment: Hint: For the sum, geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

It converges for any $x$ as you can compare the series with the geometric series without the $(\cos x)^n$. And if you want to take it a step further like finding the sum, then the series is: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac{\cos x}{2}\right)^n=\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{\cos x}{2}}= \dfrac{2}{2-\cos x}$

Comment: Yes , i compared it, and i knw it converges, but I dnt knw how to get the sum.

Comment: Oh okay, u used the formula a/ 1-r because of the geometric series. But if we used that we should get a exact number. Since it converges at any value x, i should leave it like that ?